# Omit null value columns while executing select query on a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, null, notnull

I have a table that has 700 columns. I need to execute a query based on a condition but I dont want to browse through 700 columns and look for data. I want to eliminate columns that has null values only.

For eg:
select * from table1 where message in ('value1', 'value2')

The result of this statement has 700+ columns.

Table:

| Column A | Column B | ...Column ZA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value1 | Null | ...Value1 |
| Value2 | Null | ...Value2 |

While displaying the select statement results I want to omit Column B since it only has nulls.

So far I'm using python to filter the output file not able to do it in sql statement.
I want to omit the null columns from the result of select statement.

Comment: `UNPIVOT` could be a nice solution except for that is doesn't allow to pass a variable with column names, and with 700+ columns it's a no-go. But I believe you'll have to try to unpivot the table somehow. Maybe this approach may help: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-unpivot-multiple-columns-into-tidy-pairs-with-sql-and-bigquery-d9d0e74ce675